# What are "recent hot answers"?

Tags: support, answers

I just saw a reference to "recent hot answers" when checking out the newly coined [csst](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csst) tag.

Are hot answers in general, and recent hot answers in particular new SE things? If I wanted to go looking for some hot answers, can I search or filter for them?

Will there be a "Hot network answer" or an "HNA" list where we can look at other sites' hot answers as well?

[image: What are "Recent Hot Answers"?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this isn't anything new, just . . . something that was never well-publicized. [It's been around since at least late 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157238/274942), and probably longer - so definitely not new.

I don't think you can search all of a site's hot network questions from this interface; you can do it per-tag by the link

```
https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-name/hot
```

and just substitute in the tag name for `tag-name` - or click the "more" you see at the bottom of your image. The default *seems* to show the hot answers from the last month, sorted by score, in most cases, but you also select day, week, year, and all time. But you can't sort by date or activity.

That said, you *can* use [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to solve the problem and perform a query of your own; this became possible [a couple of years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324663/274942) when entering the HNQ [started to be logged in a question's history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324643/274942) and is therefore in the `PostHistory` table. You could probably pretty easily modify Glorfindel's SQL query from that first link to take the returned list of hot network questions and show their answers instead, add fields to include or exclude certain tags, or sort by different answer features, like votes or recent activity.

Comment: Okay got it, *thanks!*